# How do I obtain data from a JSON file when a checkbox is checked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, checkbox

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm trying to build a little flashcard game that allows users to select different libraries of flashcards when they click a checkbox and I am having some difficulty implementing this feature.  What I want my code to do is change the dataset that gets displayed when someone clicks on a checkbox of their choice.

Here is a picture of the checkboxes and the flashcards:

[image]

This is the HTML code for the checkboxes:

```
<div id="flashcard_sets">
    <div id="card_group">
        <h3><u>Choose Flashcard Set</u></h3>
        <input type="checkbox" id="question_words" name="Question Words" value="Question Words" class="vocab">Question Words
        <input type="checkbox" id="verbs" name="Verbs" value="Verbs" class="vocab">Verbs
        <input type="checkbox" id="nouns" name="Nouns" value="Nouns" class="vocab">Nouns
    </div>
</div>
```

My data is saved in an external json file stored in this variable: `var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";` that contains this information:

```
{"Question Words":[{"q":"What is the word for 'where' in Italian?","a":"Dove"},
{"q":"What is the word for 'when' in Italian?","a":"Quando"},
{"q":"What is the word for 'why' in Italian?","a":"Perché"}],
"Verbs":[{"q":"What is the verb for 'I am'?","a":"Sono"},
{"q":"What is the verb for 'you are'?","a":"tu sei"},
{"q":"What is the verb for 'he is'?","a":"lui è"}],
"Nouns":[{"q":"gioco","a":"game"},
{"q":"buco","a":"hole"},
{"q":"amico","a":"friend"}]}
```

This is the javascript function that displays the flashcard:

```
var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";
var cardIndex = 0;
var qs;
var numCards;
var maxIndex;
var isFlipped = 0;

function displayCard() {
    $("#card").fadeOut(400,function(){
        colorIndex = getRandomInteger(0,3);
        $("#card").addClass(colorClasses[colorIndex])
        isFlipped = 0;
        var newHtml = "<h2>Question Words</h2>";
        var chosen_one = $("#card_group input[type=checkbox]:checked")
        if(chosen_one){
            var selection = chosen_one.attr("name");
            newHtml += qs["selection"][cardIndex]["q"];
        }else{
            newHtml += qs["Question Words"][cardIndex]["q"];
        }
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = newHtml;
    }).fadeIn(400);
}
```

This is the code that grabs the external json data to display on the flashcard:

```
var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";
var cardIndex = 0;
var qs;
var numCards;
var maxIndex;
var isFlipped = 0;

function init() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(jsonObject) {
        qs = jsonObject;
        var chosen_one = $("#card_group input[type=checkbox]:checked")
        if(chosen_one){
            var selection = chosen_one.attr("name");
            numCards = qs["selection"].length;
        }else{
            numCards = qs["Question Words"].length;
        }
        maxIndex = numCards-1;
        displayCard();
    });
}
```

I know I definitely did something wrong and I've tried several solutions but now I don't really know what to do to get this working.  If anyone could provide some help or advice on this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Link to full code that isn't working: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uhau56byCGOLJiQxmFFg?p=preview

Link to original code without the code you wrote, and with javascript functions embedded into the HTML file.  You can take a look at this to see what I want to do with my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/kxzTPX3VhYKZGNDkDoWX?p=preview

Comment: Do you need checkboxes (or would radio buttons be better)? ie, are you wanting multiple types of questions or just one type?

Comment: it doesn't matter if they are radio buttons, as long as the appropriate  questions are displayed when a user selects the box.

Comment: but do you want all three selected? because from your question it seems like you dont. In which case, you should be using radio buttons

Comment: I would want only one set to be selected.  Would changing the checkboxes to radio buttons fix my problem?

Comment: @jzm no I'm still having some trouble trying to put into my code. I think the problem is that the displayCard() function has changed to become changeCard(chosen_one) which now takes a parameter, where my previous function didn't

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you want to use radio buttons because you only want one to be selected.

So I've slightly re-written it to get you on the right path.

```
function init() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(jsonObject) {
        qs = jsonObject;
        changeCard("Question Words");
    });
}

$('.vocab').change(function () {
  var chosen_one = $(this).val();
  changeCard(chosen_one);
});

var changeCard = function(chosen_one) {
  $("#card").fadeOut(400,function(){
      isFlipped = 0;
      var newHtml = qs[chosen_one][cardIndex]["q"];
      maxIndex = qs[chosen_one].length;
      $('#questionTitle').html(chosen_one);
      $('#question').html(newHtml);
      console.log(maxIndex);
  }).fadeIn(400);
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="card">
  <h2 id="questionTitle"></h2>
  <div id="question"></div>
</div>

<div id="flashcard_sets">
<div id="card_group">
    <h3><u>Choose Flashcard Set</u></h3>
    <label for="question_words"><input type="radio" id="question_words" name="vocab" value="Question Words" class="vocab" checked>Question Words</label>
    <label for="verbs"><input type="radio" id="verbs" name="vocab" value="Verbs" class="vocab">Verbs</label>
    <label for="nouns"><input type="radio" id="nouns" name="vocab" value="Nouns" class="vocab">Nouns</label>
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WjDKys?p=preview

Comment: Hmmmmm.....I see that what you've written on Plunker works but I'm having some trouble implementing it into my code.  Is it possible to re-write the changeCard(chosen_one) function so the function doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: Of course, but how would it know what's been chosen? the default is `changeCard("Question Words");`. I changed your code because it was quite messy. $(.vocab).change() listens to the change event on the radiobuttons, and then get's the value of the selected radiobutton, and sends it to changeCard()

Comment: My code still doesn't change when I select the radio buttons, and I'm not too sure why.  I'm thinking I have to re-examine my whole code.  do you think having <body onload="init();"> would prevent the changes from occurring compared to putting init(); in the javascript file?

Comment: Yes. If you're using jquery, NEVER use HTML javascript event tags

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, I really appreciate you helping me.  I'll trying fiddling around with my code and try to make some modifications to make it work.  If I can't get my code to work within the next few days is it possible you could take a look at my source code?

Comment: Hey, I really appreciated you helping me out the other day.  I'm still having trouble implementing the code you wrote the other day.  I've included two links to my post that you can click above.  The first link is to a set of code that doesn't work and contains the code you wrote the other day.  The second link is to my original file without any modifications or changes.  You can take a look at this second link to get an idea of what I am trying to do.  I hope I am not asking for too much.  The code in the first link is rather messy!(I'm a noob, sorry!).  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("input").checked){
```

This line is definitely going to be a problem. `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of Elements, and because arrays do not have a `checked` attribute, this statement will evaluate to undefined. Because undefined has a false truth value, anything inside of your if statement will not be executed.

Now, this does not mean that you can't search through the array of `input` elements yourself to find the checked box. You will have to do a for-loop to check the boxes yourself:

```
var chosen_one;
for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++){
    var box = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
    if (box.checked) {
        chosen_one = changeCardset();
        numCards = qs["chosen_one"].length;
    }
}
if (!chosen_one) numCards = qs["Question Words"].length;
```

You will also have to change your `changeCardset` function to have a similar for-loop for finding the box (if any) that is checked.

Comment: I tried what you said and it doesn't work.  I've put in the edited code up above so you can take a look at what I did.  Do you know where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The key part that is going wrong here is that

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

is returning a NodeList. In order to look at any parameters of this list, it needs to be iterated. A more appropriate approach would be to look for the checked one.

```
var chosen_one = $("#card_group input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

however, the problem here is that there can be up to 3 checked. Addressing this will fix the problem in your code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work.  Do you have any other suggestions or tips?

Comment: @Jamaal - This is something which occurs multiple times in your code. Did you change all occurrences?

Comment: I put in the changes to all the occurrences but now I'm getting this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined with refers to this line of numCards = qs["selection"].length; the init() function.  I've also implemented the changes above, maybe I didn't do it correctly.  Could you take a look at my edited code?  Thank you

Comment: @Jamaal - "selection" is a static string, you want the variable selection there. Try `qs[selection].length;` (no quotes).